# Basis of space spanned by a set

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether or not the set $B = \left\{(2,3,2),(1,1,-1) \right\}$ is a basis of the space spanned by the set $A = \left\{(1,2,3),(5,8,7),(3,4,1) \right\}$.

Comment: can you express every vector from A as linear combination of vectors from B

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! What have you tried? To encourage people to help you solve  the question, please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: perform Gaussian elimination on the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & 5 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 4 \\
2 & -1 & 3 & 7 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
and compute the rank of
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 & 3 \\
2 & 8 & 4 \\
3 & 7 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Let $M_B = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$

Let $M_A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \end{bmatrix}$

Try to solve the augmented system $\begin{bmatrix}  M_B | & M_A\end{bmatrix}$, if it is consistent, then it is a basis if  $b_1$ and $b_2$ are linearly independent.